# How to search the value when value is stored as encrypted

Tags: iphone, database, encryption

in my database i store the student information in encrypted form.

now i want to perform the search to list all student which name is start with "something" or contains "something"

anybody have idea that how can perform this type of query?
Please suggest

Comment: Can you tell us more about what encryption algorithm you used? Also, encrypting all the data in the database sounds like a bad idea - if you could tell us more about why you did that, maybe we can find a better solution

Comment: Also, you might want to go back through old questions and accept some more answers.

Comment: I see that many of your posts are about iPhone development - is that the case here as well?

Comment: hi james, i want to develop a application in iPhone which store some field (not all) as encrypted.all analysis is fine except one which is how can i perform search when full value is not supplied. so if i want to search the student which name is start with "A" or contains "A", then how i adjust the query

Comment: hi jams, one more thing.
i apply the encryption on application level. my mean is that whenever i update the database(insert/update), first i encrypt the value in application and after that i insert this value in database.
i am not apply the encryption on database level.

Answer (score 1):

Any decent encryption algorithm has as one of its core features the fact that it's impossible to deduce anything about the plaintext just by looking at the encrypted text. If you were able to tell, just by looking at the encrypted text, that the plaintext contained the string `william`, any attackers would be able to get that information just as easily, and you may as well not be encrypting at all.

The only way to perform this kind of operation on the data is to have access to the decrypted data. Using the model you've described - where the database only ever sees the encrypted data - it's not possible for the database to do this work, as the database has no access to the data it needs.

You need to have the data you're wanting to search on decrypted. The only complete way to do this is to have the application pull *all* the data out of the database, decrypt it, then do the filtering/sorting/whatever in your application. Obviously this is not going to scale well - but that's surely something you took into consideration when you decided to encrypt the data before putting it in the database.

Another option would be to store fragments of the data unencrypted. For example, if you have a `first_name` field and you want to be able to retrieve all records where `first_name` begins with `a`, have a `first_name_first_letter` field. Obviously this isn't going to scale well either - if you want to search for all records where `first_name` contains `ill`, you're going to have to store the complete `first_name` unencrypted.

There's a more serious problem with this solution though: by storing unencrypted data, you're leaking information about the encrypted data. The more unencrypted data you store, the more you leak. The more you leak, the more clues you're leaving for an attacker to defeat your encryption - plus, if you've stored the bit they were interested in unencrypted, they've already won.

Comment: you mean i select all record from database. and then decrypt them and finally compare them the search value?if yes, then i think this is not the feasible solution

Answer (score 1):

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899190/database-encryption) points to [SQLCipher](http://www.zetetic.net/software/sqlcipher) - it's an implemention of sqlite that does the encryption in the database. It seems to be targeted towards your use case - it's even already used on a couple of iPhone apps.

However, it has the database doing the encryption, not the application. This lets the database also handle the decryption, and hence the database is able to inspect the contents of the fields and do the searching you're looking for.

If you're still insisting on not doing the encryption in the database, this won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the equivalent of "starts with" and "contains", you might be able to do something with a bit field and the bitwise logical operators.

Not sure on the syntax you'd use, exactly (I'm a bit rusty on SQL) but the idea would be to create an additional field for each record which has a bit set for each letter that occurs in the name, then do something like:

SELECT * from someTable where (searchValue & bitField)>0

You then need to iterate over those records, decrypt them, and determine whether they **actually** meet the criteria you really wanted to search on (since you'd get a superset of the desired records back from the search).

You'd obviously be leaking some information about the contents of the field by doing this,  but you can probably reduce that by encrypting the bitfields as well, or by turning on a few extra bits in each bitfield, so you can't tell "bob" from "bobby", for example.

I'm curious about what sort of security goal you're trying to meet with this encryption, though. If you describe the model a bit more, you might get better answers.